# how to import com.android.mms.R?

Tags: android, mms

In some class of android source code ,they import com.android.mms.R, but I can't do it after I tryied. Are there any methods be used to import com.android.mms.R?

Answer (score 1):

If your class already imported `import com.android.R`, delete it. and clean the project rebuild it. from projects>clean

if you have used any of Res by R.XXXX your project R will automatically get imported or do **ctrl + shift + O**

Also if it doesn't work go to property(right click on project)>Android here select target version as 4.0, then clean it will go.. first remove `import com.android.R` line from class

Comment: what you said doesn't work out. After I do ctrl + shift + O, the project can't import  com.android.mms.R